# Covert one polygon in a MULTIPOLYGON to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with R

Tags: shapefile, r, polygon

I am fairly new to GIS (recently returning after a very long hiatus).  I have a `gpkg` file (`fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg`) for Kruger National Park, South Africa, obtained here (scroll halfway down and click '`Download all (33.7 MB)`':

https://zivahub.uct.ac.za/articles/dataset/Spatial_Data/11585136

There is only one `layer` in the `gpkg` file (`fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs`) with `Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON`.  There are 11 `features`, which I assume means 11 `polygons`.  There are eight `fields` which I think means every `polygon` has eight `attributes`.

I wish to extract just the `polygon` for Kruger National Park, not any of the neighboring nature or game reserves.  Then I wish to convert the `polygon` for Kruger National Park into a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

Below is my `R` code attempting to do that.  This `R` code is a little messy because I show the results of many steps and includes several dead ends:

```
# I do not know which of these libraries is critical and which are not needed
library(GISTools)
library(here)
library(mapdata)
library(mapproj)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(mapview)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(tidyverse)
mapviewOptions(fgb = FALSE)

# Check available layers in 'fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg'
st_layers("C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/Kruger_National_Park/fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg")
# Driver: GPKG 
# Available layers:
#               layer_name geometry_type features fields
# 1 fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs Multi Polygon       11      8

# import 'fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs' from 'fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg'
Kruger <- st_read(dsn = "C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/Kruger_National_Park/fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg", layer='fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs')
# Reading layer `fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs' from data source `C:\Users\mark_\Documents\ctmm\Kruger_National_Park\fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
# Simple feature collection with 11 features and 8 fields
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 30.88982 ymin: -25.5303 xmax: 32.032 ymax: -22.32804
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

# View the data
Kruger
Kruger[11,]

# Select just the park, not any of the nature or game reserves
# But I do not know how to convert the KNP MULTIPOLYGON into a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
# This was a dead end for me
KNP <- Kruger[Kruger$SITE_TYPE == "National Park",]
KNP
# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 8 fields
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 30.88982 ymin: -25.5303 xmax: 32.032 ymax: -22.32804
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   WDPAID              CUR_NME WMCM_TYPE MAJ_TYPE     SITE_TYPE    D_DCLAR LEGAL_STAT GIS_AREA                           geom
# 2    873 Kruger National Park  National       PA National Park 1926-07-26 Designated  1916915 MULTIPOLYGON (((31.38601 -2...

# Plot just the park polygon with no fill
plot(KNP["WDPAID"], col=NA)

# Split the Kruger MULTIPOLYGON into separate polygons
Kruger.polygons <- st_cast(Kruger, "POLYGON")
# Warning message:
# In st_cast.sf(Kruger, "POLYGON") :
#   repeating attributes for all sub-geometries for which they may not be constant

Kruger.polygons
# Simple feature collection with 12 features and 8 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 30.88982 ymin: -25.5303 xmax: 32.032 ymax: -22.32804
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# First 10 features:
#        WDPAID                                CUR_NME WMCM_TYPE MAJ_TYPE      SITE_TYPE    D_DCLAR LEGAL_STAT    GIS_AREA                           geom
# 1      351116     Sabie Sands Private Nature Reserve  National       PA Nature Reserve 1965-01-27 Designated   59570.419 POLYGON ((31.60339 -24.7093...
# 2         873                   Kruger National Park  National       PA  National Park 1926-07-26 Designated 1916915.360 POLYGON ((31.38601 -24.4843...
# 3   555563989                  Pafuri Nature Reserve  National       PA Nature Reserve 1954-09-08 Designated   19755.774 POLYGON ((31.16474 -22.3293...
# 4   555570576 Rondalia-Letaba Private Nature Reserve  National       PA Nature Reserve 1965-12-15 Designated   21918.745 POLYGON ((31.06034 -23.6464...
# 5   555571052            Letaba Ranch Nature Reserve  National       PA Nature Reserve 2016-06-17 Designated   24909.868 POLYGON ((31.01752 -23.7567...
# 5.1 555571052            Letaba Ranch Nature Reserve  National       PA Nature Reserve 2016-06-17 Designated   24909.868 POLYGON ((31.06072 -23.6469...
# 6   555564082         Umbabat Private Nature Reserve  National       PA Nature Reserve 1969-05-21 Designated   14505.518 POLYGON ((31.37728 -24.1101...
# 7        9072                 Manyeleti Game Reserve  National       PA Nature Reserve 1967-12-15 Designated   17253.707 POLYGON ((31.59821 -24.6119...
# 8   555563621     Buffelshoek Private Nature Reserve  National       PA Nature Reserve 1969-03-05 Designated    4113.504 POLYGON ((31.60138 -24.6988...
# 9      300443        Klaserie Private Nature Reserve  National       PA Nature Reserve 1972-01-26 Designated   59045.239 POLYGON ((31.19972 -24.0533...

# Select just the Kruger National Park POLYGON
KNP.polygon <- Kruger.polygons[Kruger.polygons$SITE_TYPE == "National Park",]
# KNP.polygon
# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 8 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 30.88982 ymin: -25.5303 xmax: 32.032 ymax: -22.32804
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   WDPAID              CUR_NME WMCM_TYPE MAJ_TYPE     SITE_TYPE    D_DCLAR LEGAL_STAT GIS_AREA                           geom
# 2    873 Kruger National Park  National       PA National Park 1926-07-26 Designated  1916915 POLYGON ((31.38601 -24.4843...

plot(KNP.polygon["WDPAID"], col=NA)

# How do I convert the KNP.polygon POLYGON into a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?
# This does not work:
writeOGR(KNP.polygon, dsn="C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/my_KNP", layer="my_KNP", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
# Error in writeOGR(KNP.polygon, dsn = "C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/my_KNP",  : 
#  inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE

# How do I convert the Kruger MULTIPOLYGON into 11 separate SpatialPolygonsDataFrames?
# This does not work:
Kruger$CUR_NME
y <- unique(Kruger$CUR_NME)
for(i in y[1:length(y)]){
 temp = Kruger[Kruger$CUR_NME == i, ] 
         writeOGR(temp, dsn="C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/my_KNP", i, driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer=TRUE)
}
# Error in writeOGR(temp, dsn = "C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/my_KNP",  : 
#  inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE
```

Comment: Try `as(KNP.polygon,"Spatial)`

Comment: @dieghernan Thank you.  It did indeed work in this line: `writeOGR(as(KNP.polygon,"Spatial"), dsn="C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/my_KNP", layer="my_KNP", driver="ESRI Shapefile")`  It ran without returning an error and created a `shapefile` that could be imported into `QGIS`.

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked to create a `shapefile` for the park that could be imported either into `QGIS` or back into `R` which might be all I really need.

```
library(GISTools)
library(here)
library(mapdata)
library(mapproj)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(mapview)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(tidyverse)

mapviewOptions(fgb = FALSE)

# Kruger National Park file 'fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg' obtained here:
# https://zivahub.uct.ac.za/articles/dataset/Spatial_Data/11585136

# Check available layers in 'fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg'
st_layers("C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/Kruger_National_Park/fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg")

# import 'fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs' from 'fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg'
Kruger <- st_read(dsn = "C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/Kruger_National_Park/fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs.gpkg", layer='fixedKNPandBoundaryPAs')

# Writes a shape file to the appropriate directory which then can be read into QGIS
st_write(Kruger[2,], "C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/my_Kruger/my_Kruger.shp")

# Read the shape file 'my_Kruger.shp' back into R
st_layers("C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/my_Kruger/my_Kruger.shp")

KNP.imported <- st_read(dsn = "C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/my_Kruger/my_Kruger.shp", layer = 'my_Kruger')
KNP.imported

plot(KNP.imported[,1])
```

The approach described here did not seem to work I guess because of the `geom` column in `Kruger`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511524/how-do-you-convert-from-a-multipolygon-to-a-spatial-polygons-data-frame